# wrong location in the browser

Tags: networking

I live in Finland, but in Firefox, Google estimates the location of the device as St. Petersburg. I use Finland as a VPN address. The VPN service provider is Hide.me. I can't see all online content because of Russian censorship or the content is not shown to Russia. I use a Huawei LTE modem (mobile network).  I also can't use the Live Patch feature. How to fix this? [location information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bbsj.png)

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As your question is not related to the Ubuntu OS, you may not find your answer here. I'd suggest that you work directly with [the Hide.Me community](https://community.hide.me/). There's a very related issue discussed here: https://community.hide.me/threads/finland-location.4093/